# HIVE - "skip.footer.line.count" doesn't work in Impala

Tags: hadoop, hive, cloudera, impala

I am having flat files being delivered to hdfs. The general structure of files are as below:

```
<header - 2 rows>
 <data>
<footer - 1 row>
```

I am having an external hive table build on top of this dataset. Below is my hive ddl:

```
create external table ext_test
(
  id string,
  name string, 
  age string
) row format DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
  STORED AS TEXTFILE
  LOCATION '<hdfs file location>'
  TBLPROPERTIES ('skip.footer.line.count'='1', 'skip.header.line.count'='2')
```

When i query `select * from ext_test` in HIVE; i am getting the exact number of rows as expected from the external table. But when i run the exact same query in IMPALA, i receive one additional row which is basically the footer property.

**e.g:** The below example will clear out the scenario:

Sample Data in the Feed:

```
Header,Sample-03122018,
ID,NAME,AGE
1,R,10
2,RR,11
3,RRR,12
Footer,End of Report,
```

Output when i run select command in **HIVE** using the above DDL *[Expected Output]*:

```
1,R,10
2,RR,11
3,RRR,12
```

Output when i run select command in **IMPALA** using the above DDL: *[Issue]*

```
1,R,10
2,RR,11
3,RRR,12
Footer,End of Report,Null
```

Did you face similar issue? If yes, please advice me of the suitable solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is not implemented in Impala yet, see this Jira [IMPALA-7196](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IMPALA-7196).

Impala doesn't recognize `skip.footer.line.count`, so it is effectively ignored.

The workaround is to query using filter `WHERE ID <> 'Footer'`, or cut the file footers before loading files into table directory.